# Reuse the ActionListener

Tags: java

I am working on a GUI card game and I am wondering if there is a way I can improve my code. Here is my situation.

I have three cards: A, B and C. Players are free to replace a card by clicking on one of three buttons: button1, button2 or button3, respectively.

```java
class rpbtn implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Image1 = new ImageIcon(myDeck.myDeck[5].filename);
        label_Image1.setIcon(Image1);
    }
}
```

The variable names are fixed. Yet, I don't want to create 3 similar inner class by just changing variable name from 1 to 2 or 3. Is there a way that I can reuse/improve these codes?
Thank you.

Comment: Class `ActionEvent` has members `actionCommand` and `source`. See methods `getActionCommand()` and `getSource()`. If you don't explicitly set the `actionCommand`, via method `setActionCommand()`, I believe it defaults to the button's text. You can check this by looking at the source code for class `ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you can use constructors, setters, etc. in your inner class. So, if the code for actionPerformer is the same, but only changing the element affected you could have one unique inner class with a parameter inside for which perform the operations. Something like this:

```
private class MyListener implements ActionListener {

    Object obj;

    private MyListener(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        //Operations on obj
    }

}
```

You can test this with this JFrame example (just instantiate it):

```
package tests;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow() {

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");

        MyListener ml1 = new MyListener(label1);
        MyListener ml2 = new MyListener(label2);

        button1.addActionListener(ml1);
        button2.addActionListener(ml2);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        getContentPane().add(label1);
        getContentPane().add(label2);
        getContentPane().add(button1);
        getContentPane().add(button2);

        pack();
        setLocation(600, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private class MyListener implements ActionListener {

        JLabel label;

        private MyListener(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            label.setVisible(!label.isVisible());
        }

    }

}
```

Even if you want the code more compact, you can use the MyListener instances as anonymous:

```
button1.addActionListener(new MyListener(label1));
```

Hope this helps you to adapt it to your particular needs.

Comment: So, when label in the class MyListener changes, label1/label2 changes at the same time?

Comment: Or only the "label" changes in the private class? Thank you.

Comment: In the sample code, each button controls the label that you pass as an argument to the listener you attach to the button. If you want one button control more than one elements (always regarding the context of your question), you would need to define more arguments in the constructor of `MyListener`, and control them in the `actionPerformed` method. On the other hand, you can control the same element(s) with several buttons, as long as you attach the same listener to those buttons (and pass the necessary element to the listener constructor).

Comment: @Www The label changes in the private class? Yes and no. The change is performed in the private class instance. But it is triggered from a button outside. Also take into account that the label is declared outside the private class, and then you use it as an argument in the instantiation of the listener; and remeber that that argument is just a reference to the label declared outside. So, if you put the label in a container, the toggle action is performed in the private inner class, but that change is reflected outside.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to change the label icon on clicking the button. Just pass the ImageIcon as a constructor argument and use it.

```
    class rpbtn implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon img = null;
    public rpbtn(ImageIcon img){
        this.img = img;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Image1 = new ImageIcon(myDeck.myDeck[5].filename);
        label_Image1.setIcon(this.img);
    }
}
```

Comment: "label_Image1" should also be a variable. The button replaces the corresponding image.